# Switching from python-mode.el to python.el

Tags: python, emacs, editing

I recently tried switching from using `python-mode.el` to `python.el` for editing python files in emacs, found the experience a little alien and unproductive, and scurried back.  I've been using `python-mode.el` for something like ten years, so perhaps I'm a little set in my ways.  I'd be interested in hearing from anyone who's carefully evaluated the two modes, in particular of the pros and cons they perceive of each and how their work generally interacts with the features specific to `python.el`.

The two major issues for me with `python.el` were

1. Each buffer visiting a python file gets its own inferior interactive python shell.  I am used to doing development in one interactive shell and sharing data between python files.  (Might seem like bad practice from a software-engineering perspective, but I'm usually working with huge datasets which take a while to load into memory.)
2. The skeleton-mode support in python.el, which seemed absolutely gratuitous (python's syntax makes such automation unnecessary) and badly designed (for instance, it has no knowledge of "`for`" loop generator expressions or "`<expr 1> if <cond> else <expr 2>`" expressions, so you have to go back and remove the colons it helpfully inserts after insisting that you enter the expression clauses in the minibuffer.)  I couldn't figure out how to turn it off.  There was a `python.el` variable which claimed to control this, but it didn't seem to work.  It could be that the version of `python.el` I was using was broken (it came from the debian emacs-snapshot package) so if anyone knows of an up-to-date version of it, I'd like to hear about it.  (I had the same problem with the version in CVS emacs as of approximately two weeks ago.)

Comment: You don't say why you tried switching to python.el. What was good about it?

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, I do not see the behavior you are seeing in issue #1, "Each buffer visiting a python file gets its own inferior interactive python shell."

This is what I did using python.el from Emacs 22.2.

C-x C-f foo.py
[insert: print "foo"]

C-x C-f bar.py
[insert: print "bar"]

C-c C-z [*Python* buffer appears]

C-x o

C-c C-l RET ["bar" is printed in *Python*]

C-x b foo.py RET

C-c C-l RET ["foo" is printed in the same *Python* buffer]

Therefore the two files are sharing the same inferior python shell. Perhaps there is some unforeseen interaction between your personal customizations of python-mode and the default behaviors of python.el. Have you tried using python.el without your .emacs customizations and checking if it behaves the same way?

The major feature addition of python.el over python-mode is the symbol completion function python-complete-symbol. You can add something like this

```
(define-key inferior-python-mode-map "\C-c\t" 'python-complete-symbol)
```

Then typing

```
>>> import os
>>> os.f[C-c TAB]
```

you'll get a *Completions* buffer containing

```
Click <mouse-2> on a completion to select it.
In this buffer, type RET to select the completion near point.

Possible completions are:
os.fchdir                          os.fdatasync
os.fdopen                          os.fork
os.forkpty                         os.fpathconf
os.fstat                           os.fstatvfs
os.fsync                           os.ftruncate
```

It'll work in .py file buffers too.

Comment: Using python.el from emacs-snapshot package in Ubuntu 8.04 (Emacs 23), I don't seem to have the python-complete-symbol function.

Comment: The information in this answer is out of date now with Emacs 24.1.50. The above defun has been removed and replaced by `python-completion-complete-at-point` and few other completion mechanisms. I'm not too clear how these work, otherwise I would edit the answer.

Answer (score 3):

1. I can't reproduce this behavior on Emacs v23.1, this must have been changed since then.
2. Forget about any mode's skeleton support and use the hyper-advanced and extensible [yasnippet](http://code.google.com/p/yasnippet/) instead, it's really worth a try!

Answer (score 2):

Note nearly everything said here is obsolete meanwhile as things changed.

python-mode.el commands are prefixed "py-" basically, you should be able to use commands from both, nonewithstanding which one was loaded first.

python-mode.el does not unload python.el; beside of python-mode-map, which is re-defined.

The diff is in the menu displayed and keysetting however, the last one loaded will determine.

Answer (score 1):

python-mode.el is written by the Python community. python.el is written by the emacs community. I've used python-mode.el for as long as I can remember and python.el doesn't even come close to the standards of python-mode.el. I trust the Python community better than the Emacs community to come up with a decent mode file. Just stick with python-mode.el, is there really a reason not to?

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, but it's rather authoritarian.  I'm looking for a comparison of the packages' features, on a practical level.  I don't care about the authors' perceived credentials.

Answer (score 1):

python-mode.el has no support triple-quoted strings, so if your program contains long docstrings, all the syntax coloring (and associated syntaxic features) tends to break down.

my .02

Comment: I just tried this out with python-mode.el version 5.1.0 and couldn't reproduce it: docstrings work just fine with font locking.  I don't think a bug like this would be present for a long time in *the* predominant python mode for Emacs, docstrings are everywhere, somebody would have catched the bad behavior pretty soon.

Comment: Ah! *Now* I know what you mean...  I just discovered this bug myself in a docstring: quoting *inside* a docstring does indeed break syntax highlighting.

Comment: @paprika,@Gyom: FWIW, it looks like the triple-quoted strings issue was addressed in [5.2.0](https://launchpad.net/python-mode/+milestone/5.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

Debian has deleted the python-mode package, alas, so I felt compelled to try python.el.  I loaded it and ran "describe-bindings".  It appeared to be designed for elisp coders who think `c-X ;` is the intuitive binding for commenting a line of Python code.  (Wow.)  Also, I found no way at all to comment a region of code, or, rather, no binding with the strings "region" and "comment" in it.

Good old python-mode can still be cloned via `git clone https://gitlab.com/python-mode-devs/python-mode.git`.  It was last edited a week ago at this writing, so it's safe to assume it's not abandoned.